# Automatically open reports in search?

Tags: report, splunk

In Splunk Enterprise 6.3.0, is there a way to make reports automatically open in the Search app ?

Right now, I have to open a report, click on Edit, and then hit "Open in Search" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dashboard with the saved search, and then every time you open the dashboard you open it also.